# How to remove the secondary database created by sp_add_log_shipping_secondary_database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to remove the secondary database created by sp_add_log_shipping_secondary_database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_secondary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189467.aspx)

In general whenever there is an add procedure there also exists a drop or delete proc